# Get data from external api using guzzle laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to get data from an external API using `Guzzle 4.0` in laravel 4.

**I have tried that**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=************');
echo "<pre>";
dd($response->getBody());
```

**Its giving me Guzzle object instead of JSON response**, I have directly hit that url in browser that is giving correct json data.

**Response I get by guzzle:**

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream)#151 (6) {
["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream":private]=>
resource(6) of type (stream)
["size":"GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream":private]=>
NULL
["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream":private]=>
bool(true)
["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream":private]=>
bool(true)
["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream":private]=>
bool(true)
["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream":private]=>
string(10) "php://temp"
}
```

Can some one please tell me how can I get correct json data.

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting the body to a string:

```
dd((string) $response->getBody());
```

The `getBody()` method does in fact return an object, this is by design. It is automatically cast to a string if you try to use it as a string, say with `echo`.

In your `dd()` call though, you need to explicitly cast to a string, or else you will get the object output.

This is from the docs:

> The body of a response can be retrieved using the getBody method. The body can be used as a string, cast to a string, or used as a stream like object.
>
> ```
> $body = $response->getBody();
> // Implicitly cast the body to a string and echo it
> echo $body;
> // Explicitly cast the body to a string
> $stringBody = (string) $body;
> ```

See here for more details:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#using-responses

Comment: thanks for your answer, by using this I can get the string, but my problem is not solved because I also need to store values in database :(

Comment: If you can get the string, you can parse it as json using `json_decode`. Or, by just calling `$response->json()` as Jason mentions below. Once you have the parsed JSON data, you can pull out the individual values and store in your database.

Answer (score 2):

If your response is indeed JSON, you can call the `json()` method on the response object to return a JSON array.

```
print_r($response->json());
```

This does the cast and parse in one call, which I feel is a little cleaner.